# Is there a way to add an Custom Redirect inside my Publishing Site Collection on sharepoint online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, page-layout, publishing-site, jsom

when i was working on enterprise wiki site collection inside an on-premise deloyment, i use to add the following code inside a farm solution, then add the generated custom WebPart to my enterprise wiki home page:-

```
public class CustomWikiPageBase : PublishingLayoutPage
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TreeField"]) 
            && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TreeValue"]))
        {
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?TreeField={1}&TreeValue={2}",
                SPContext.Current.ListItem.ParentList.DefaultViewUrl,
                Request.QueryString["TreeField"],
                Request.QueryString["TreeValue"]));
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TreeField"]))
        {
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?TreeField={1}",
                SPContext.Current.ListItem.ParentList.DefaultViewUrl,
                Request.QueryString["TreeField"]));
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

as mentioned in this link [Link](https://markuspersson.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/add-metadata-navigation-on-custom-page-layouts/). The reason to include this method, is to allow metadata navigation inside the Tree view. i did this appraoch on 3 on-premise deployment and they worked well.

but now i am working on sharepoint 2013 online. so can anyone adivce how i can add the above method, or similar method? as i mentioned inside the on-premise i use to add this method inside a farm solution,and farm solutions is not an option inside SP online ?

I mean can i use the same logic from my above method,inside a JSOM or any other script which i can use inside SP online to do the redirect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Script Editor WebPart on your desired Page, put following Code into it (or create a Sandboxed No Code Solution WebPart using Visual Studio)

```
<script>

   var treeField = GetUrlKeyValue("TreeField");
   var treeValue = GetUrlKeyValue("TreeValue");

   if(treeField && treeValue){
      window.location = "http://contoso.com?TreeField="+treeField+"&TreeValue="+treeValue;
   }

</script>
```

If you need a dynamic URL of your List you can access the _spPageContextInfo Object and parse the listview URL out (for example _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath will give you the URL to the form eg.: "*/sites/Listname/Forms/DispForm.aspx*")

More to Read: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29766.sharepoint-understanding-the-sppagecontextinfo-object.aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript
https://praneethmoka.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/some-useful-javascript-variablesfunctions-in-sharepoint/

Comment: your code will work if i remove this `if(treeField){
      window.location = "http://contoso.com?TreeField="+treeField;
   }` i am not sure why you added ? thanks

Comment: I just coded a quick sample based on your requirements. you had the same check above

Comment: ya i know , but i have to remove the `if(treeField){ window.location = "http://contoso.com?TreeField="+treeField; }` for it to work... not sure why .

Comment: Sure. I removed the last statement